# Extract a column data with Input command in a csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, numpy

I need to extract column data with user defined column name through Input command. user should enter the column name and accordingly that particular column data is displayed or processed for further calculation.

Here is my code.

```
# Importing required libraries
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
  
# Read the data into a series
df=pd.read_csv("Modified.csv")

#Input Column Name
col1=str(input("Enter Column Name (Case sensitive) :  "))
col2=str(input("Enter Column Name (Case sensitive) :  "))

# Creating a series of data 
x=df[['col1']]
y=df[['col2']]

#Calculate mean and Standard deviation.

mean_x = np.mean(x)
sd_x = np.std(x)

mean_y = np.mean(y)
sd_y = np.std(y)
```

Comment: There is no question here, no error ? replace 'col1' by col1 and 'col2' by col2 without the '

Comment: I have done that, facing this error now.      ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv")
x1 = input("write the column name?")
```

if x1 in df.columns This code will work correctly:

```
value_mean = df[x1].mean()
value_std = df[x1].std()
```

You can use the above code for any number of inputs.
You can also use loops to get high input and operation:

```
for i in range(2):
    x = input("column name?")
    mean = df[x].mean()
    std = df[x].std()
```